# Can we nominate candidates for the 2013 moderator elections?

Tags: support, feature-request

So I know that on cross validated we can nominate ourselves for the moderator position, but are we able to nominate others for the position?  I do not see an option for this but there a few people I can think of that I would like to nominate if they themselves do not do it.  even if they do not want the position (and could be the reason they do not nominate themselves) I think its a very nice way of saying we appreciate everything they do for the cross validated community at large.

Answer (score 11):

The moderator elections are fairly well announced and documented on the site - I'd suggest that anyone paying sufficiently little attention to the site to not notice the elections going on is probably poorly suited to being a moderator.

Which means, in all likelihood, if someone hasn't put their name in, it's because they don't want to be moderator. And if someone doesn't want to be a moderator, they really shouldn't be, from either the standpoint of the community, or from "Don't foist unpaid obligations on strangers".

I'd suggest, if you *really* think someone would make a good moderator, that you contact them (many people have Twitter usernames and the like in their profiles) or leave a comment to that effect, perhaps in response to a well-written post in CV's meta site.

Answer (score 8):

There are better ways to show appreciation than nominating someone Moderator (offer a bounty for example for answering above and beyond the call of duty, for example.)

Additional effort has to be gone into if more than a set number of nominations are received; ten or more nominations results in the Primary system kicking in, effectively a round of voting to choose the best (or most voted for) candidates prior to the election proper.

I have no problem with this if ten or more people want to nominate themselves, but there is no point having extra voting if people *don't* want the job.

Better would be to contact a particular user and see if they would mind being nominated. That way you can express your thanks *and* solicit their opinion on whether they would mind being nominated.